# Sharepoint Microsoft Graph API limit

Tags: api

I am trying to make a an application that will use the Microsoft graph API to connect to Sharepoint to do various tasks.

Recently I have found that there is a throttling/blocking limit for the API, see: [Microsoft Documentation Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online)

Now I have some questions I want to clarify,
if I have a tenant that contains an app that calls more than 6000 calls/min "the maximum allowable limit".

- would it just throttle for the remaining of the minute then continue normally after or what?
- can I do anything to exceed that limit? "contacting support, bigger license, etc."
- can I bypass this limit by creating multiple apps instead of one and splitting the load between them or is this limit is tenant wise? **(is this limit per app or per tenant?)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are building an application that uses a logged in user's security context - like an spfx solution or any other browser-based application - then you have nothing to worry about.

Throttling could occur if you have a single account context - like a client id doing client credential flow (or app-only) operations on a large scale, like a migration or bulk update of some kind.

If you think your application might be susceptible to throttling, you'll need to handle that in your code by backing off for a bit if you receive a 429. This is pretty standard when dealing with cloud based SaaS APIs at scale.

To answer your other questions

- No, you cannot expand your throttling threshold through licensing. Your SharePoint tenant shares resources with other tenants under the covers so throttling ensures you'll be a good citizen.
- The documentation you linked explicitly says not to create multiple applications to do the same work. You might get away with it, but you're risking destabilizing your farm and support would not look kindly on you if you need them and they find out about it.